# How to make reserve-network-port work with maven spring project

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I am trying to implement reserve-network-port with my maven spring project.

My POM

```
 <plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
                <execution>
                <id>reserve-network-port</id>
                <goals>
                <goal>reserve-network-port</goal>
                </goals>
                 <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                 <configuration>
                     <portNames>      
                         <portName>tomcat.http.port</portName>
                     </portNames>
                  </configuration>
            </execution>
         </executions>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.18</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
               <goals>
                <goal>verify</goal>
               </goals>
              <configuration>
               <systemProperyVariables>
                  <build.profile.url>${build.profile.url}</build.profile.url>
                 <test.server.port>${tomcat.http.port}</test.server.port>
               </systemProperyVariables>
               <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests>             
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
```

${tomcat.http.port} is returning null for me.

I am also getting the prot no reserved when my maven build is started

```
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.10:reserve-network-port (reserve-network-port) @ account-service ---
[INFO] Reserved port 58140 for tomcat.http.port
```

Comment: Is this a spring boot project or a spring project? And what are you trying to do?

Comment: It is a spring boot project. I am trying to execute the integration tests and I want to ensure that spring boot test starts the server at random ports. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: We got the solution by using @SpringBootTest(classes = AccountServiceApplication.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT).